# How to print lines between TicTacToe board

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have made a 2-player console tic tac toe program but the board that is displayed while playing the game is blank cells except for the side and bottom notation. I would like print lines in between the rows and columns but I don't know how. Here is the code involving my board:

```
public void createBoard()
        {
            //This method creates the 3x3 board and fills the board with 0s
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
                if(row > 0) System.out.println("-+-+-");
                for (int column = 0; column < board[0].length; column++) {
                    if(column > 0) System.out.println("|");
                    board[row][column] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        public void displayBoard(){
            //creates right amount of cells for 3 rows
            for (int row=0; row < board.length; row++)
            {
                //spaces between row notation and board + prints row notation
                System.out.print("\t" +(char)('a'+ row) + " "); 
                //creates right amount of cells for the 3 columns
                for (int column=0; column < board.length; column++)
                {
                    if(board[row][column]==BLANK){
                        System.out.print("\t");
                    }
                    else if(board[row][column]==X){
                        System.out.print("\tX");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print("\tO");
                    }
                }
                //blanks on right side of board
                System.out.println();
            }
            //spacing between columns
            System.out.println("\t \t1 \t2 \t3");
            checkTie();
        }
```

Comment: Just print out | (or sign) and _ or - between the Fields.

Comment: @Speedo there are lots of tic-tac-toe examples to follow on SO and other web resources: http://www.coderslexicon.com/a-beginner-tic-tac-toe-class-for-java/

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the features of your console. The most simple way that works almost everywhere is to use the two characters `|` (bar) and `-` (minus). You may also want to use a `+` (plus) at the intersections.

Some terminals have specific characters to draw lines and boxes but that means your code will have to determine the type of terminal, it's capabilities and sometimes the font. There are some libraries to help you there (like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)). [laterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) is a Java library which tries to give you similar capabilities.

EDIT: Look at this code example:

```
for (int row=0; row < board.length; row++) 
{
    if(row > 0) System.out.println("-+-+-");
    for (int column=0; column < board.length; column++)
    {
        if(column > 0) System.out.println("|");
        ... print cell value ...
     }
}
```

Comment: In what way do I tinker my code to display the most commonly used bar and minus characters you mentioned? I mess up the board when I try to implement them.

Comment: You need to use these characters instead of `\t`.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. Can you look at my updated code where I tried to implement what you did?

Comment: @Speedo: Get a piece of grid paper.  Draw a tic tac toe board on the grid paper.  **Carefully** count the grid squares and transfer those counts to your print and println statements.

Comment: @Speedo: Why do you expect my code to work inside of the `createBoard()` method?